# Windows 10 ProfSvc delays boot significantly

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-services, windows-10-v1909

I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 1909, my system is desktop i5-8500 3GHz 16GB RAM 120GB SSD + 3TB HDD for file storage.

For a long time, Windows used to display the login screen in about 20 seconds after powering on my system. However I have noticed in the last few months (even when I was running build 1903) this time period has increased significantly. My system now needs over 2 minutes to display login screen after power on. From the disk LED I see there's lots of disk activity during this period.

To find out what is causing this delay, I enabled detailed messages on startup through group policy. I eventually found that during the booting process, the ProfSvc was the cause for this delay.
This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5s11.jpg) shows the message, which is sitting there for about 1.5 minute with dots spinning and the disk working.

Any ideas why this service would cause such delay during boot? My PC is on my home network, and has 3 Microsoft user accounts (1 as administrator, 1 standard user and 1 child account). SSD health status is good (96% from crystaldiskinfo), 60% space usage. System fully updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after much experimenting I've found the cause of the problem. The solution was to delete all files in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp. For some reason this folder is not cleaned up by Microsoft's Disk Cleanup tool. There were lots of files, about 50.000 files and 9GB. Probably some of those files got corrupted, and the system boots much faster now.

Comment: I noticed the same problem. This solution definitely corrected the problem.

Comment: can confirm this as the solution for me.  However, my temp folder still seems to regularly balloon out with loads of small files. Already back to 45k small .tmp.node and OProcSessId.dat files and folders

Comment: Yes unfortunately you need to periodically clean up the folder manually yourself. Haven't found out a solution to keep the temp folder clean of junk old files. Really hope Microsoft does something about this one day.